# decode a Codable struct from API call and a mockup file simultaneously

Tags: swift, codable, jsondecoder

I am currently working on a project where I am calling a webservice that returns me a JSON that I parse using `Codable`, like so :

My Struct:

```
struct User: Codable {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
}
```

API response :

> { "name": "Romiro", "age": 27 }

Decoding code :

```
let decoded = try! JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data)
```

---

We decided to extend the `User` infos by adding new fields like so :

```
struct User: Codable {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
    var detail: Detail
}

struct Detail: Codable {
    var id: Int 
    var dob: Date 
}
```

However **the backend is not developed yet**, so the API response is still

> { "name": "Romiro", "age": 27 }

Is there a proper way to mock up only the `var detail: Detail` part, by loading it from a `detail-mock.json` file in project resources that matches the structure of `Detail`, but in the mean time keeping the API call for the pre-existing `User` part ?

By doing this, I would be able to keep all the logic of calling the endpoint, and shunting the only part that is under development, still by calling

```
let decoded = try! JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data)
```

Furthermore, is there a way to do so without altering the json response from the API? I do not want to manually append the *detail* part to je json response.

*Note: Obviously, the `User` struct is an example, on my project this is a much more complex struct*

Comment: Do you want to add the value of detail manually after User object os created?

Comment: you can do something like this  var detail: Detail?. The keys which can be nil or keys which are likely to be not present in json mark them as optional

Comment: you mean `var detail: Detail?`, then decode the `Detail` from the file and setting it to my object ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement custom decoding on `User`, like this:

```
struct User: Codable {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
    var detail: Detail

    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case name, age, detail
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        age = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .age)
        if let detail = try container.decodeIfPresent(Detail.self, forKey: .detail) {
            self.detail = detail
        } else {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "mockupDetail", withExtension: "json")!)
            self.detail = try JSONDecoder().decode(Detail.self, from: data)
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the `if` statement in `init`. That is where I decide whether to read the `detail` from the actual json, or the mocked json.

This way, you don't need to make `detail` optional, but you would need to manually decode the other properties.

Answer (score 1):

First of all set `detail` as `Detail?` type, i.e.

```
struct User: Codable {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
    var detail: Detail?
}
```

You can create 2 separate objects for `User` and `Detail`, and the set the `detail` object as `user.detail`, i.e.

```
do {
    var user = try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: userData)
    let detailData = Data() //replace this with the data obtained from Detail api
    let detail = try JSONDecoder().decode(Detail.self, from: detailData)
    user.detail = detail
} catch  {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: that would imply setting `var detail: Detail` optional?